# MAUI Authentication - Linking WebAuthenticator to WebView

Tags: .net, authentication, google-signin, maui, facebook-login

Apologies if this has been asked before. I've had a good search around and I can't find anything directly related.

I am trying to wrap a mobile website (.Net 6 MVC, hosted as an Azure App Service), into a MAUI Mobile app using a WebView. We don't need any fancy mobile app code and the site itself is mobile friendly, so all nice and straightforward until it comes to authentication...

We have our own login service (carried out via a seperate WebAPI/MS Identity) and also Google and Facebook login options (linked to said MS Identity setup). Our own login service works perfectly within the MAUI WebView. The social options don't work (at least on Android where I'm testing) due to a `403 - disallowed_useragent` error, which is down to a security precaution to prevent phishing attacks - all fair enough and understood.

I've explored the idea of using WebAuthenticator, however none of the examples seem to point me in the right direction. I'd be logging in the user in my MAUI app code, then I can't seem to see how I would share this session/login information with the WebView, which essentially would be running a totally seperate session up in my web code. I would essentially need the WebView to inherit or share this successful login information and continue the session as per the mobile site.

Any pointers here would be massively appreciated.